# POST request org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, spring, security

Using spring security with jwt.

My spring security config:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    private final exceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(exceptionHandler);
    }
}
```

When I send GET Request everything is fine. But when I send POST:

`org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource`

If i add `.csrf().disable()`   it will help, but i don't understand how it works. Why is Get request OK but post without `.csrf().disable()`  throwing an exception?

Can i pass POST requests without `.csrf().disable()`  part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To protect MVC applications, Spring adds a CSRF token to each generated view. This token must be submitted to the server on every HTTP request that modifies state (PATCH, POST, PUT and DELETE — not GET). 

This protects our application against CSRF attacks since an attacker can't get this token from their own page.

for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

Comment: I have a similar issue but I cannot fix it. Can you help me if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843944/spring-boot-microservices-rest-template-401-unauthorized-error